# How to check if the output of a function is redirected?

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

On *nix systems I can easily detect if the program is run on tty or the output is plain stream (pipe or file) and thus adjust the output accordingly (e.g. pretty print or serialize). How to do the same in PowerShell?

I'd like my function to either output the result as object for manual processing (when executed in script or piped to other commands) or use something like `Format-Table -AutoSize` when invoked directly from PS prompt.
What's the proper way to achieve that in PS?

Comment: PowerShell console host implicitly pipe any interactive output to `Out-Default` command, so you can say, that output always redirected.

Comment: PowerShell outputs objects, not text, so I'm not sure you need to do what you think you need to do. Just let it output and let the user decide how to format the output.

Comment: It turns out that this question was already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549776/can-i-determine-if-a-powershell-function-is-running-as-part-of-a-pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend leaving the decision of whether or not to use formatting cmdlets to the user. If anything I'd add a [default display property set](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/03/quick-hits-set-the-default-property-display-in-powershell-on-custom-objects/) to the output objects, so that PowerShell displays only a select subset of properties by default (full property set can still be displayed by calling the format cmdlet with `-Property *`).

```
$properties = 'a', 'b', ...   # list of property names
$object = ...                 # your object

$defaultPropertySet = New-Object Management.Automation.PSPropertySet('DefaultDisplayPropertySet', [string[]]$properties)
$standardMembers = [Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]]@($defaultPropertySet)
$object | Add-Member -MemberType MemberSet -Name PSStandardMembers -Value $standardMembers
```

Note that this requires PowerShell v3 or newer.