# determine if function return value is used?

Tags: powershell-core

Is there a way to determine if the return value of the current function is assigned to an other variable or piped as input to the following pipeline element?

I want to write something like:

```
function Do-Something {

  $functionResult = <some result from complained algorithm>

  if ( Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned ) {
    return $functionResult
  } else {
    $functionResult | set-Content "outputfile.txt"
  }
}
```

I am asking if something exists like the method Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned. It should check if the return value is used later.

My requirement is similar to the question here [Can I determine if a PowerShell function is running as part of a pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549776/can-i-determine-if-a-powershell-function-is-running-as-part-of-a-pipeline)

With $myinvocation I can determine if the result of my function above is used in a later function call inside the Pipeline. What I want to obtain is, if my function result is assigned to a variabel outside, like

```
$outsideVariable = Do-Something
```

If so, my function should return a value, if not, my function should write the result to a file, and not return anything.

I hope this new explanation is clearer.

Thanks for your thoughts. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are never capturing the result of the function call thus it is used in the If test then discarded as shown in the two runs below.

```
Function Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned {

  Return ,$True
}
if ( Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned ) {
  return $functionResult
} else {
  $functionResult | set-Content "outputfile.txt"
}
```

Output:

```
The variable '$functionResult' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:6 char:10
+   return $functionResult
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (functionResult:String) [], Ru 
   ntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

```
Function Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned {

  Return ,$False
}
if ( Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned ) {
  return $functionResult
} else {
  $functionResult | set-Content "outputfile.txt"
}
```

Output:

```
The variable '$functionResult' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:8 char:3
+   $functionResult | set-Content "outputfile.txt"
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (functionResult:String) [], Ru 
   ntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

However, if you capture the output in your If test then all works as required.

```
Function Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned {

  Return ,$True
}
if ( $($FunctionResult = Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned) ) {
  return $functionResult
} else {
  $functionResult | set-Content "outputfile.txt"
}
```

Ouptut: value $functionResult is returned to the calling program

```
Function Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned {

  Return ,$False
}
if ( $($FunctionResult = Test-ReturnValueIsAssigned) ) {
  return $functionResult
} else {
  $functionResult | set-Content "outputfile.txt"
}
```

Output: file Outputfile.txt is created in the current directory.

Comment: I updated the original question. Sorry it obviously was not clear enough

Comment: Sorry, but if I understand (and I'm not sure I do) I don't see any way in PowerShell to determine that. Maybe some of the Guru level people here can help.